# Grabbing a single element by ID from page loaded with Request.HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I'm loading a page that contains many elements and, once loaded, need to be able to grab one single DIV with the id of "panel_1". This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
var Req = {
    main: new Request.HTML({
        onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript){
            var panel_1 = responseElements.filter('#panel_1');
            Blinds.updatePanel('panel_1', panel_1);
        }
    })
};
Req.main.send({
    method:'get',
    url: 'default.php'
});
```

`Blinds.updatePanel()` is just a function that takes that content and inserts it into the proper DIV.

This is all working fine except for Internet Explorer. For some reason it just chokes on `responseElements.filter('#panel_1')`. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE:**

For some reason when I try this in IE8:

```
var Req = {
    main: new Request.HTML({
        onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript){
            alert(responseElements.filter('#panel_1').get('id'));
        }
    })
};
```

I receive this error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 6 Dec 2010 00:07:58 UTC

    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 228
    Char: 74
    Code: 0
    URI: http://ideacity.smallparade.com/js/mootools/mootools-core-1.3-full-nocompat-yc.js
```

Other browsers alert with "panel_1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er. `array.filter` is--to the best of my knowledge--a progressive enhancement for `Array` type in mootools that acts exactly as this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter (adds this *callback method* to browsers that don't support it). Typical use is via a function that iterates elements and keeps those that return `truly` ( http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:filter ) :

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function() {
        var panel, elTemp = $$(this.response.elements).filter(function(el) {
            return $(el) && el.get && el.get("id") == 'panel_1';
        });
        if (elTemp.length)
            panel = elTemp[0];

        alert(panel.id);
    }
}).send();
```

see it work with your html: http://jsfiddle.net/PCTsz/3/

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff: I had thought of `getElement()` but it appeared to give back an array filled with nulls and the element when used on a collection http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/VBPtw/5/

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/NF2jz/481/ - the $$() on the response tree is not the same as on the dom.

Comment: I took your jsFiddle code and dropped into my page. It works when I paste it exactly as you have it, but when I change the url to `default.php` (which is in the same directory) it throws this error: `TypeError: Result of expression 'element[name]' [undefined] is not an object.` Why? Here's what I changed: `new Request.HTML({ url: 'default.php', data: { html: "<p>Text <a href='' id='foo'>echoed</a> back to <a href='' class='foo'>request</a></p>", delay: 1 }, method: 'post', onComplete: function() { alert($$(this.response.tree).getElement("#foo")); }}).send();`

Comment: keep in mind the example fiddle was geared up towards the jsfiddle testing environment, which requires you to provide the response the server sends via the `data.html` value. can you show me the exact html your `default.php` spits out so we can adjust the fiddle / test for it?

Comment: Could IE be having an issue with the fact that I'm using HTML5 inside the DIV I'm trying to grab?

Comment: Yeah, we're doing this for SEO purposes. Each link on the page needs to point to real, full pages, but I'm loading only the panels that I need via Ajax. Unfortunately there is no way I can wrap everything in a textarea as each page needs to be able to display if linked to directly. Also, the textarea would break SEO.

Comment: ah fixed. it has a problem applying methods as not all elements that come through have prototypes that allow extending in IE so `el.get()` may not work. via elements collection: http://jsfiddle.net/PCTsz/3/ - added checks for `$(el)` and `el.get` before getting the id.

Comment: So it HAS to be inside a textarea?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! One last question... how do I update this to allow for grabbing multiple elements (basically panel_1-5)?

Comment: I assume I just need to update the return to `return $(el) && el.get && (el.get("id") == 'panel_1' || el.get("id") == 'panel_2' || el.get("id") == 'panel_3' || el.get("id") == 'panel_4' || el.get("id") == 'panel_5');` and grab each panel via the `elTemp` array?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PCTsz/4/ - set an array of ids you like and filter to get only them.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - So is this an issue with the fact that I'm using HTML5 elements in the page I'm loading? I ask because I'm unable to style these new elements. I found the innershiv script (http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/) but I'm unable to figure out how to work it into your example.

Comment: i don't think so, html5 will have nothing to do with it. works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PCTsz/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`var panel_1 = responseElements.filter('#panel_1');`

to:

`var panel_1 = $$(responseElements).filter('#panel_1')[0];`

You could also use `$(element)` for single elements or `document.id(element)` in newer mootools builds. The reason for this in IE is that using the `$()` or `document.id()` forces IE elements to 'grab' the mootools element methods. I believe the same should go for a collection of elements using the `$$(elements)` method [Mootools Element docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element)

Comment: Hmm. This returns 'null': $(responseElements)

Comment: I'm an idiot... that's for a single element... sorry... try wrapping it in `$$(responseElements)` I'll update my answer

Comment: Okay, so that returns an object, but then how do I specifically grab the div with "panel_1" id?

Comment: The filter will return an `array` of elements. So even if you're expecting only one to return it'll be of type `array` so you should be able to get that element via `panel_1[0]`  here is a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/VBPtw/

Comment: Hmm. But my original issue is that filter doesn't seem to work in IE, for some reason.

Comment: By the way, this page I'm grabbing is a full HTML page and #panel_1 is one of many elements on the page, so I can't really use array ids.

Comment: It's strange. `$$(responseElements).filter()` returns an object but `$$(responseElements).filter('#panel_1')` throws an error.

Comment: true... I assumed the filter wasn't working in IE because mootools wont apply the the extra element methods to IE elements unless you used mootools to create them... as for the many id's I assumed since you were filtering with an `ID` there would only be one element returned, being the element with `panel_1` as the ID hence the [0] array index reference to get just that one... Otherwise I'm not sure as to why it's bombing in IE and not the others. :/

Comment: That is odd that it's throwing an error with that filter applied... Do you have a link I can look at?

Comment: If I'm loading a page with many elements is filter the best way to go about grabbing just one of them?

Comment: It really depends on what `responseElements` is. IF it's a array of elements then `filter` would be your best bet I believe and if there is only one element with `panel_1` as an ID then [0] would be it. IF `responseElements` is an element with children then you could use `getElement('#panel_1')` as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/VBPtw/1/

Comment: I just thought of something... your `responseElements` I'm guessing it's a string of the HTML? and Not actual elements? if so you could create an element to render the string into real elements. Then run `getElement('#panel_1')` on that element. as in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/VBPtw/4/

Comment: hmm... :/ again the only idea I can think of as to why you get that error in IE is the whole Mootools not apply the `Element` methods directly to the prototype in IE. My only suggestion is to try this: `alert($(responseElements.filter('#panel_1')).get('id'));`